# Number of digits

Tags: oz, mozart

I'm programming a function In Mozart-Oz that returns the mirror of a number, for example

Mirror(1234) will return 4321

So anyway I have the idea how to, but I'm stuck because **I need an in-built function that returns the number of digits (returns an integer) of an integer**.

I tried the {Length X} function but I have no idea what it returns...

Here's my code (that doesn't work) to understand the context of my problem.

```
declare
fun {Mirror Int Acc}
if Int==0 then Acc
else {Mirror (Int div 10) (Int mod 10)*(10^({Length Int}-1))+Acc}end
end

{Browse {Mirror 1234 0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have done that:

```
declare
fun{Mirror X Y}
   if X==0 then Y
   else {Mirror (X div 10) (X mod 10)+Y*10}
   end
end
{Browse {Mirror 1234 0}}
```

or, if you want only one argument:

```
declare
fun{Mirror X}
   fun{Aux X Y}
      if X==0 then Y
      else {Aux (X div 10) (X mod 10)+Y*10}
      end
   end
in
   {Aux X 0}
end
{Browse {Mirror 1234}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the number of digits by converting to a string and taking its length:

```
  NumDigits = {Length {Value.toVirtualString Int 10 10}}
```

BTW, the `^` operator has a different meaning the Oz. You probably want the `Pow` function.

Comment: OZ is very frustrating...
I figured out a couple of things
If you give an Int to Value.toVirtualString, the browser doesn't show
If you give a String to Length, the browser doesn't show, I tested it with actual simple strings as in {Length 'AZERTY'} the browser didn't show but when i did {Length "AZERTY"} it worked...the thing is, when i put the string i got from the toVirtualString in a variable, and give it to the function Length it doesn't work... so what should i do

OMG i punched the wall so much... if you please could guide me through this i'm a complete begginer in this language